# Как выделить тегом определены текст [PHP]

Tags: php, html

Задачка для меня трудна, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью. Есть определенный текст:

```
$string = '<p class="text-align__center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [[{"id":99,"media":"url:media"}]]. Autem beatae eaque eius fugiat fugit ipsam laudantium modi, molestiae nisi omnis, quae tempore unde veritatis vero vitae! Nostrum officiis quaerat quo!</p><p class="text-align__center">[[{"id":101,"media":"url:media"}]], consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus consequatur est eum fugiat iusto laboriosam maxime quas quibusdam voluptates? Ab deleniti dicta doloribus eius error illum minus repellendus sunt voluptate.</p>';
```

Соотвественно, присутствует куски, которые необходимо выделить тегом `p`. При условиях:

- Данными кусками является контент заключенный в `[[{(.*)}]]`;
- Данные куски уже хранятся в теге `p`;
- Перед или позади куска может уже быть тег `p`;
- В json массиве может храниться различная информация.

Хотелось бы итогом получить строку, где данные куски выделяются тегом `p`, что будет иметь вид `<p>[[{(.*)}]]</p>`. Вот итоговая строка, для понимания:

```
$result = '<p class="text-align__center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p><p>[[{"id":99,"media":"url:media"}]]</p><p>. Autem beatae eaque eius fugiat fugit ipsam laudantium modi, molestiae nisi omnis, quae tempore unde veritatis vero vitae! Nostrum officiis quaerat quo!</p><p class="text-align__center">[[{"id":101,"media":"url:media"}]]</p><p>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus consequatur est eum fugiat iusto laboriosam maxime quas quibusdam voluptates? Ab deleniti dicta doloribus eius error illum minus repellendus sunt voluptate.</p>';
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и совет.

Comment: ну и замените подстроку `[[{` на `</p><p>[[{`, и аналогично с концом.

Comment: @teran я бы заменил. Как было описано, что необходимо учитывать, что перед данным выражением `[[{` может уже присутствовать данные тег также, как и после `}]]`. Можно, конечно, сначала заменить но потом необходимо будет проверить на наличие пустого контента в самом теге `p` и убрать подобные случаи.

Comment: то есть возможно там уже стоит `</p><p>[[{` вы об этом?

Comment: регулярки негативный просмотр назад, тогда в помощь `(?<!<p>)\[\[`

Comment: @teran, о а это идея. Что-то не подумал об этом.